# If I know $P(x)$ and $P(y|x)$, how can I know $P(y)$?

Tags: conditional-probability

If I need to compute $P(y)$ and I only know $P(y|x)$ and $P(x)$.

I know that:

$$P(y|x)=\frac{P(y,x)}{P(x)}$$

This is the contingency table for $P(y|x)$:

```
 P(y|x) |   +x   |  ¬x  |
-------------------------
   +y   |  0.91  | 0.03 |
-------------------------
   ¬y   |  0.09  | 0.97 |
-------------------------
```

And the probability of $x$:

```
        |   +x   |  ¬x  |
-------------------------
  P(x)  |  0.05  | 0.95 |
-------------------------
```

How can I compute $P(y)$?

Comment: There is insufficient information - for example if P(y|x) were 1, that could mean that P(y) =1 or it could also mean P(y) = P(x) if totally dependant.

Comment: @Cato, I have updated my question. If you need more info, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: You have an equation $a=b/c$  and you know $a$ and $c$. So you can get $b$ just by multiplying both sides of the equation by $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(y,x) = P(y|x) P(x)$

$P(y) = \sum_x P(y,x) = \sum_x P(y|x) P(x) $

Comment: Your last formula is wrong.

Comment: @VansFannel Why do you think that?

Comment: I think is $P(y) = \sum_x P(y,x) = \sum_x P(y|x) P(x) $ (Law of total probability). I need to compute $P(y)$.

Comment: @VansFannel You are right with your formula. And you are right, that the formula of NicNic8 is wrong.

Comment: @VansFannel My former formula was correct for P(x).  I have now fixed it for P(y).

Comment: @NicNic8 No, your formula was wrong: $P(x) = \sum_y P(y,x) = \sum_y P(y|x) P(x) $. Or $P(x) = \sum_y P(y|x) P(x) $. You are trying to compute $P(x)$, using $P(x)$.

Comment: I see.  It’s correct now.